# How do you determine if balls distinguishable- TwelveFold way

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

In the TwelveFold Way questions how do you determine if the balls are distinguishable or indistinguishable?

Here is an example question:

"From a set of 10 different sport magazines, 5 different car magazines, and 3 different wildlife magazines, how many different ways is it possible to choose 2 magazines if they must be on different subjects?"

In this case how would you know if the "balls" are indistinguishable? I understand why the bins would be distinguishable as the problem clearly states it. Although, I don't understand how you can tell whether the balls are distinguishable.

Answer (score 1):

The balls here are distinguishable. If you had two red balls, they would be indistinguishable. If you had two labeled red balls, they would be distinguishable. The fact that each magazine is different denotes it as distinguishable. Labeling is really the crux of whether or not two objects are distinguishable. People, labeled balls, different issues of a magazine subscription, etc., are all distinguishable. Unlabeled balls of the same color, two candy bars of the same type and brand (ie., two Kit-Kat bars of the same size), etc., are all indistinguishable.

In this case, you look at each pair of categories and choose a magazine from each. So for Sports/Cars pairs, you have: $10 \cdot 5$ options. For sports/wildlife pairs, there are $10 \cdot 3$ options. Then for car/wildlife pairs, there are $5 \cdot 3$ options. Notice each pair of categories are disjoint (ie., car/wildlife precludes sports/wildlife), so by rule of sum you add them up: $50 + 30 + 15 = 95$.

Now if all the magazines of each type were indistinguishable, you would have $\binom{3}{2}$ such ways of choosing the subscriptions. So if no two car magazines were distinguishable, it wouldn't matter which one you chose. Just like if you had two unlabeled red balls, choosing one over the other makes no difference.

Comment: Hey, 

Thanks for the response. I appreciate it. Although, when we went over this problem in class the professor mentioned that the "balls" were indistinguishable. This resulted in us using the the choose formula. I guess I'm getting confused over the whole balls and bins concept. Is there a simpler way to go about doing these type of combinatorics problems with restrictions?

Comment: It depends on the wording of the problem. Since the magazines of a given type were noted as different, I would have thought them to be distinguishable. I would perhaps talk with your professor in this case. Combinatorics is a pretty intuitive subject, so it comes down to developing intuition and doing problems rather than finding a formulaic approach. So I'm sorry, but there is no simpler way.